# d3.js Horizontal bar graph - keeping Y axis in the middle of the graph

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have a horizontal bar graph where the labels sometimes run off the end of the canvas. So for example if the Y axis is to the far left of the canvas, based on the distribution of the data values, instead of the label showing 'Chevrolet Corvette', only 'Chevro' will be visible. If I could keep the Y axis in the middle of the canvas (i.e. point 0,0 is in the middle) regardless of the data distribution, it would help solve my issue. Is it possible to keep the Y axis in the middle of the canvas and have the bars scale accordingly? fiddle:
        https://jsfiddle.net/Kavitha_2817/2e1xLxLc/

```
var margin = {top: 30, right: 10, bottom: 50, left: 50},
    width = 500,
    height = 300;


var data = [{value: -10, dataset:"Corvette", year: "1975"},
{value: 40, dataset:"Lumina", year: "1975"},
{value: -10, dataset:"Gran Torino", year: "1971"},
{value: -50, dataset:"Pomtiac GTO", year: "1964"},
{value: 30, dataset:"Mustang", year: "19655"},
{value: -20, dataset:"Camaro", year: "1973"},
{value: -70, dataset:"Firebird", year: "1975"}];

var svg = d3.select('body').append('svg').attr('width', width + margin.left + margin.right).attr('height', height + margin.top + margin.bottom).append('g').attr('transform', 'translate(' + margin.left + ',' + margin.top + ')');
```

// set the ranges

```
var y = d3.scaleBand()
    .range([height, 0])
    .padding(0.1);

var x = d3.scaleLinear()
    .range([0, width]);

// Scale the range of the data in the domains
x.domain(d3.extent(data, function (d) {
    return d.value;
}));
y.domain(data.map(function (d) {
    return d.dataset;
}));

// append the rectangles for the bar chart
svg.selectAll(".bar")
    .data(data)
    .enter().append("rect")
    .attr("class", function (d) {
        return "bar bar--" + (d.value < 0 ? "negative" : "positive");
    })
    .attr("x", function (d) {
        return x(Math.min(0, d.value));
    })
    .attr("y", function (d) {
        return y(d.dataset);
    })
    .attr("width", function (d) {
        return Math.abs(x(d.value) - x(0));
    })
    .attr("height", y.bandwidth());

// add the x Axis
svg.append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
    .call(d3.axisBottom(x));

// add the y Axis
let yAxisGroup = svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "y axis")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + x(0) + ",0)")
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I updated you [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2e1xLxLc/7/) to do what I understood you try to achieve. I did it by simply computing the domain manually to make it symetrical:

```
var min = d3.min(data, function(d){return d.value});
var max = d3.max(data, function(d){return d.value});
var absMax = Math.max(Math.abs(min), Math.abs(max));
x.domain([-absMax, absMax]);
```

This way, the min and max being equal but of opposite signs, the 0 will be at the center.

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for, Thank You!